# Safe use of git merging in a simple source code

Tags: git, merge

Please, consider the next scenario, starting with the following file named `main.f90`:

```
program main
  integer :: i

  i=0


  !This is "the comment in the middle"


  print *, i

end program
```

I want to put this code under git version control, so I do:

```
git init
git add main.f90
git commit -m "First commit"
```

Later, I start a new branch named "abranch" and I add `i=i+1` to `main.f90` before "the comment in the middle"

```
git checkout -b abranch
sed -i '6i  i=i+1' main.f90
git commit -a -m "Add 1 before the comment"
```

Then I checkout the master again, and I add `i=i+1` after "the comment in the middle"

```
git checkout master
sed -i '9i  i=i+1' main.f90
git commit -a -m "Add 1 after the comment"
```

Until here, if I compile and execute `main.f90` in "master" or in "abranch" I will get `1` as output, that is the desired result. However, I want to have only one copy of my program, so I merge "abranch" into the master:

```
git merge abranch
```

The thing is that now the code will output `2`, because the merged file is:

```
program main
  integer :: i

  i=0

i=i+1

  !This is "the comment in the middle"

i=i+1

  print *, i

end program
```

My point is that `git merge` can give unexpected results in a very silent way. It seems like git is not safe for the version control of my programs.... but I thought that was the main use of it. So I'm probably using git in a wrong way. Could you explain me what I'm missing here?

Comment: No source-control program is going to be able to tell you whether two changesets interact at runtime. You still need to test your code after you merge.

Comment: I think what you're missing is the merge onto `abranch` from `master` before merging back into `master`. This will let you test `abranch` before getting to the main branch.

Comment: @jeremytwfortune that help a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works right. Git takes care of versioning file contents, not analysing programs. No version control system that exists these days can do what you expect, because that's exactly it - "what you expect", not "right thing to do".

Imagine that instead of addition you first call `foo()`, and in a branch call `bar()`. You could say "sure `foo()` already does `bar()`, so that part is not necessary". But git does not know Fortran, it doesn't know your intentions, and it doesn't know anything about symbolic execution and safety of removing `bar()`.

The merge is safe because you didn't lose any data. You get all the information from both branches and now it's up to you to decide what do you want the result to look like. If you want to protect yourself from accidental changes like that, add unit tests to your application, so that you can easily verify pre/post merge that the result is what you expect.